# Linq insert selected data into ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, linq

How can I insert a linq query into ObservableCollection data structure? Look at my code snippet:

```
    var server = from e in _fileElement.Elements("computerprefix")
        where e.Attribute("name") != null
        select new ServersLogins
        {
            Server = e.Attribute("name").Value,
            Logins = from i in e.Elements("user")
                select new ObservableCollection<Login>
                {
                    User = i.Attribute("name"),
                    Password = i.Attribute("password")
                }
        };
```

as error message I've got

```
'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<CustomCopyNas.Models.Login>' does not contain a definition for 'Password'  D:\c#\Samples\CustomCopyNas\CustomCopyNas\Views\LoginViewModel.cs
'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<CustomCopyNas.Models.Login>' does not contain a definition for 'User'  D:\c#\Samples\CustomCopyNas\CustomCopyNas\Views\LoginViewModel.cs
```

How can I do in the right way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var server = from e in _fileElement.Elements("computerprefix")
             where e.Attribute("name") != null
             select new ServersLogins
             {
                 Server = e.Attribute("name").Value,
                 Logins = new ObservableCollection(
                              from i in e.Elements("user")
                              select new Login
                              {
                                  User = i.Attribute("name"),
                                  Password = i.Attribute("password")
                              })
             };
```